# Change class for date in datepicker directive that is always visible

Tags: jquery, datetime

I am new to angularJs and jQuery and have this problem I am trying to solve. I created a datepicker directive that is always visible. I have a list of changing dates, that I want to use to update the class of dates in my calendar - different color. Whenever my list changes update the corresponding dates. I assume `beforeShowDay` is only ran once. How can I update my calendar that is always open?

```
.directive('mydatepicker', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        require: 'ngModel',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs, ngModelCtrl) {
            var options = attrs.mydatepicker;
            scope[options].changeButtonFormat = function(dateList) {
                  var i = dateList;
            }
            element.datepicker({
                altFormat: "EEEE, MMMM d, y",
                altField: "#timesheet-date",
                minDate: "-14d", maxDate: "+90d",

                onSelect: function (date) {
                    scope.$apply(function () {
                        ngModelCtrl.$setViewValue(date);
                    });
                }
            });
        }
    }
})
```

Comment: Adding functionality to code is not what CodeReview is about.